# How do I set & fetch Environment variable in AWS Lambda Project in C#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, aws-lambda, environment-variables

I have created `AWS Lambda Project` in `C#` (NOT Serverless Application)

[image]

I have defined a Environment variable in `aws-lambda-tools-defaults.json` as below

```
"environment-variables": {
 "my-api": "http://myapihost.com/api/attendance-backfill"
 }
```

In Function.cs, fetching the value as below

```
   var apiUrl = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("my-api").ToString();
```

but it always coming as `null`.

How do I set & fetch Environment variable?

Thanks!

As per comment.

[image: launch-settings.json]

[image: Function.cs]

Answer (score 28):

It's pretty close but after some digging around I found out how to actually set these for local runs using the Mock Lambda Test Tool.  It is, in-fact, inside the launchSettings.json file.  You want to drop the settings inside the Mock Lambda Test Tool section of the profiles node, not outside it.

```
{
 "profiles": {
  "Mock Lambda Test Tool": {
   "commandName": "Executable",
   "commandLineArgs": "--port 5050",
   "workingDirectory": ".\\bin\\Debug\\netcoreapp2.1",
   "executablePath": "C:\\Users\\%USERNAME%\\.dotnet\\tools\\dotnet-lambda-test-tool-2.1.exe",
   "environmentVariables": {
     "environment": "test"
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

1. Setting Environment variables [docs used](https://blog.tonysneed.com/2018/12/16/add-net-core-di-and-config-goodness-to-aws-lambda-functions/)

There are two places where you’ll need to set environment variables: development-time and deployment-time. To do this, open the launchSettings.json file from under the Properties folder in the Solution Explorer.  Then add the following JSON property:

```
    "environmentVariables": {
      "my-api": "something"
    }
```

To set environment variables at deployment-time, you can add these to the aws-lambda-tools-defaults.json file.  (Just remember to escape the double quote marks.)

```
    environment-variables, its format is: "<key1>=<value1>;<key2>=<value2>;".
```

In your case you should have

```
    "environment-variables" : "\"my-api\"=\"http://myapihost.com/api/attendance-backfill\";"
```

2. Consuming/fetching the environment variables

   Consuming the environment variables as part of the Lambda function’s logic is done intuitively in the C# code, by using the System library [aws blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/using-the-aws-lambda-project-in-visual-studio/):

   ```
   System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(<key>);
   ```

   In your case you can use the following;

   ```
   var apiUrl = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("my-api");
   ```

In [this document](http://twenty6-jc.blogspot.com/2016/12/using-environment-variables-with-aws.html) it is suggested that your approach for fetching environment variable is correct.

```
    var variableValue = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("nameOfVariable");
```

Comment: Did you try again with just Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("my-api"). Make sure your environment-variables are configured correctly.
I found two documents which differ slightly [aws thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=755106&tstart=0) and [twenty6 doc on lambda variables](http://twenty6-jc.blogspot.com/2016/12/using-environment-variables-with-aws.html)

Comment: System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("my-api") is returning null while the value is set in .json file

Comment: I updated my answer with some additional docs. Can you confirm that you fixed your aws-lambda-tools-defaults.json so that environment-variables parameter is correctly set?

Comment: I added the screenshot of launch-settings.json & Function.cs Still getting the value as null

Comment: For anyone who had this issue, it's `environmentVariables` (not `environment-variables`) in launchSettings.json

Answer (score 0):

These solutions worked. Need to set environment variables in two places 1.) deployment purpose and 2.) test locally using mock tool

serverless.template file
[image]

launchSettings.json file
[image]