# Environment Variables from launchsettings.json AWS Lambda Function Test .Net Core 3.1

Tags: c#, .net, aws-lambda, environment-variables, integration-testing

I must develop some tests for my AWS Lambda Function written in c# using .net core 3.1.

The lambda uses several environment variables that I have written on the launchsettings.json file for the local test.

I don't know why when running the application and using the "Mock Lambda test tool" all the values are retrieved and it works but when running the test from Test Explorer I have seen

```
var variable = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("variableName");
```

is equal to null.

How can I let the lambda retrieve these values during the integration tests?

Thanks to everyone

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set & fetch Environment variable in AWS Lambda Project in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54843650/how-do-i-set-fetch-environment-variable-in-aws-lambda-project-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Sadly no but thanks